# MongoDB client for OCaml

Tags: mongodb, ocaml

I can't find a MongoDB client library for OCaml, is there one? I found [something](https://github.com/kiyoto/caml_mongo) on github, but it doesn't look maintained.

I thought the next best option was to use camlidl to try and wrap the C mongo client (libmongo-client), but wondered if someone else had done this already?

Comment: Maybe this can be what you want? http://massd.github.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Philippe Veber said [on the mailing-list](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.caml.inria/51429) that he was looking for something, but apparently hasn't published code. You should contact him to ask him feedback.

I would go for the existing binding you're pointing at, and extend it. Some of the heavy lifting is already done, and it has the advantage of not forcing you to interact with C code (which is never a nice experience imho).

Comment: I managed to run a couple of queries with the project by kiyoto on github.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Mongo.ml](https://github.com/MassD/mongo) that appears to be gaining traction, it even sports in the [MongoDB community supported drivers page](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/community-supported-drivers/).